# Boost named_semaphore examples?

Tags: c++, boost, semaphore, interprocess

I have not been able to find a good example that shows how to use boost::interprocess::**named_semaphore** (not even on the Boost web site).

I could see something about interprocess_semaphore, but they seem to be quite different and I do not know if what shown for one also applies to the other.

Can anybody give me some links to such **examples**/tutorials/documentation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The major difference between `interprocess_semaphore` and `named_semaphore` is that the `interprocess_semaphore` is shared with using the shared memory ,where as `named_semaphore` doesn't need to be constructed (using construct) or stored in shared memory as it referenced by name instead of anonymously.

Named synchronization methods use different objects to access the same resource, but are using the same resource, where is anonymous synchronization methods need to share the same object in shared_memory or some other mechanism in order to access the same resource.

This means that `named_semaphore` has 3 constructors which either open or create the referenced synchronization method, in comparison to `interprocess_semaphore` which only has 1 constructor.

Both semaphore types implement `post`, `wait`, `try_wait` and `timed_wait` as expected.

Further information is available [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.synchronization_mechanisms_overview.synchronization_mechanisms_named_vs_anonymous) and [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/interprocess/some_basic_explanations.html).

One example of using a `named_semaphore` is available [here](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/graighle/20100106/1262792525)

Comment: I will take a look at your link soon... Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused by this: "Both semaphore types implement wait, notify_one and notify_all as expected."
I've never seen a semaphore that implements something like "notify_all".  It looks like these Boost semaphores implement post, wait, try_wait, and timed_wait.  Is that what you meant, or am I missing something?

Comment: You described named_condition, which is not the same thing as named_semaphore.